# Why should I put try/catch block out of loop?

Tags: c#

Here is CodeReview Guideline by Practice&Patterns team.http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/ms998574#scalenetchapt13_topic7(The link navigate to the Exception section automaticly.)

They said you should put try/catch block out of loop when you handle exception, I want to know why?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because the underlying implementation of a `try... catch` block adds overhead to the generated code, and putting that overhead in a tight loop is not a good idea, performance-wise.

Technically, if all the iterations of your loop are "equal", and the loop should stop as soon as an exception occurs, then it's better to put the `try... catch` block outside of the loop. If the loop must continue despite exceptions occurring, you'll be forced to put the block inside the loop, but you might want to review your design in that case.

Comment: +1 The only "correct" answer since it refers to the try/catch block and not just to exceptions. However, I do have designs where the processing should continue if one of the "listeners" throw an exception. I'm wonder how a rewrite could be done for that? for instance: `foreach (var listener in listeners) { try { invoke(Y); } catch (Exception err) { _logger.Warning("Client XX did bla bla", err); }}`

Comment: That's a good example: usually, in this situation, the `try` block's overhead is negligible compared to the time spent in `invoke()`. If that's not the case, however, you can use a nested loop in order to avoid catching exceptions in each iteration, which will increase performance if most of the calls to `invoke()` succeed. Something like `int i = 0, len = listeners.length; while (i < len) { try { for (; i < len; ++i) { invoke(listeners[i]); } } catch (Exception x) { _logger.Warning("Client XX did bla bla", x); ++i; } }`.

Comment: Nice solution. But as you say, it should only be used were it has been proved to be needed (by benchmarking or other measures).

Answer (score 11):

Exceptions are expensive - if you put the exception logic within a loop you risk having exceptions being thrown for every iteration in the loop. This can easily cause performance issues.

If you put the try/catch block outside of the loop, you will only need to handle a single exception.

Comment: I think the loop would be broken off certainly if an exception be thrown. Therefore, regardless of whether putting try/catch in loop or not, exception will be thrown just one time. Is that right?

Comment: @Domi.Zhang - No, if you handle the exception in your `catch`, the loop will resume.

Answer (score 2):

A `try/catch` inside a loop behaves differently from one outside the loop, unless it always rethrows the exception.

Therefore your choice will depend on your requirements: if you want to continue looping, then catch inside the loop, otherwise outside.

I think the reason for the recommendation is that `try/catch` inside a loop looks suspiciously like using exceptions for control flow.  It's flagging a potential "code smell" rather than stating a hard and fast rule.

But it's reasonable to ignore the recommendation if that's what your requirements dictate.  To take a simple but obsolete example, in a world without `Int32.TryParse` (.NET 1.x wasn't that long ago!), it would be reasonable to have a loop that parses a list of strings into integers using `Int32.Parse` in a try/catch inside the loop.

Comment: Try blocks *are* flow control statements, whether people like it or not. Either outside or inside the loop, the try block *will* control the flow *if* an exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the potential for multiple exceptions appearing in the loop which causes unnecessary overheads in your application.

If there is an error found within there then handling outside the loop makes more sense.

Comment: It certainly causes overhead; but without seeing the code it's not possible to say whether or not the overhead is necessary.